# Accelerometer not working after uploading game to the App Store

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, app-store, accelerometer

I made a space game where you use the accelerometer to move a spaceship, When I try the game on my devices (iPad, iPhone) it work well with no errors or incorrect behavior.

I upload my game to the App Store and it was approved, but when I downloaded the game from the App Store, the accelerometer wasn't working and my spaceship was stuck in one direction.

I tried many devices and they all have same problem.

Note: I used the cocos2d and box2d frameworks.

If anybody have any idea, please help!

Comment: If you don't mind telling us... what's your games name?

Comment: After this issue i remove my game from the app store by changing the availability date because it's a paid Game

Comment: Try cleaning your project and testing again, you may have accidentally changed something and not noticed while you were testing. Uploads to the app store are usually created from scratch so if you don't test from a clean project, strange bugs can pop up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UIAccelerometerDelegate 

UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;

In .m file

# pragma mark To Enable Acceleromete

self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
self.accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
self.accelerometer.updateInterval = 0.025;
self.accelerometer.delegate = self;


Use these delegates methods

#pragma Mark Accelerometer

-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
        // Set up variables
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        #define kFilteringFactor 0.5
        #define kShipMaxPointsPerSec (winSize.height*0.5)        
        #define kRestAccelX (xCallib)
        #define kMaxDiff 0.2
        #define kRestAccelY (yCallib)
        #define kMaxDiffY 0.1

        UIAccelerationValue rollingX=0;
        float accelX;

        // High pass filter for reducing jitter
        rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));    

        accelX = acceleration.x - rollingX;

        // Calculate movement for x and y axis
        float accelDiffX = accelX - kRestAccelX;///
        float accelFractionX = accelDiffX / kMaxDiff;//
        movementX = kShipMaxPointsPerSec * accelFractionX;


        // Thresh holds for x and y axis movement
        willMoveX = YES;

        if (((movementX < 45.0f) && (movementX > -45.0f)))
            willMoveX = NO;
}

#pragma Mark Accelerometer Update Methods

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
    CCSprite *player =(CCSprite *) [self getChildByTag:objPlayerShipTag];

    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];

    float oldX = [player position].x;
    float newX; 

    if (willMoveX) { 
        newX = [player position].x + (movementX * dt);
    } else newX = oldX;

    if ((newX > (screenSize.width -45)) || newX < 45.0f ) {
        newX = oldX;
    }

[player setPosition:ccp(newX,90)];

// ++++++++ To generate Bullet and Bomb Power +++++++

[self checkForCollisionWithPowersBullets]; //NEW
[self checkForCollisionWithPowersBomb];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..